# Failed to fetch 404 on Docker node image when build

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

I have this docker file with node version of 14.16.1, when I run docker-compose build

```
FROM node:14.16.1

# Prepare app directory
RUN mkdir -p /api
WORKDIR /api

ARG DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD
ENV DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD=$DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install tofrodos

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN fromdos /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Install sources
COPY . /api
RUN rm -rf /api/node_modules

RUN npm install -g pm2

RUN if [ "$DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD" = "yes" ]; then  npm install && npm run build ; fi

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

error

```
#0 2.095 Reading package lists...
#0 2.110 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.111 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.111 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.111 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 2.111 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 2.111 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 2.111 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

it was working fine just 2 monthes ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base image of `node:14.16.1` seems to be using `Debian 9/stretch` and based on the error the `apt-get update` command fails.

This happens because the stretch suite was moved from `deb.debian.org` to `archive.debian.org` as announced [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/03/msg00006.html)

You need to update the `sources.list` of the container before running the update command. The updated `dockerfile` will be:

```
FROM node:14.16.1

# Prepare app directory
RUN mkdir -p /api
WORKDIR /api

ARG DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD
ENV DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD=$DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD

# Update stretch repositories
RUN sed -i -e 's/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g' \
           -e 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' \
           -e '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install tofrodos

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN fromdos /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Install sources
COPY . /api
RUN rm -rf /api/node_modules

RUN npm install -g pm2

RUN if [ "$DO_PRODUCTION_BUILD" = "yes" ]; then  npm install && npm run build ; fi

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```